# Removing scripts from the head tag if they exist already

Tags: javascript

So i'm calling a function within another folder that goes ahead and downloads a library (jsPDF) and then runs the resulting code. However every time I click the button which triggers the function call, the scripts are added the head which ends up stopping the program from working. i'm trying to only add the scripts once, and if they are added, don't add them but continue with the rest of the code.

Call to run function

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById('submit1');

//add event listener
myBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

fetch()


});


async function fetch(){

const itemToStore = document.getElementsByClassName("itemName");
const itemQty = document.getElementsByClassName("quoteQty");
const itemPrices = document.getElementsByClassName("quotePrice");
const itemTotal = document.getElementsByClassName("quoteTotal");
const totalCost = "Total Cost" + ":" + document.getElementById("quoteTotalCost").innerText;



fn(itemToStore, itemQty, itemPrices, itemTotal, totalCost)
// getFile()



}
```

Js code

```
     async function functionCall(){
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
        for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++){ 
           if(scripts[i].getAttribute('src') == 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.0.28/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js'){
             console.log('found once')
             break;

        }

        else{
          console.log('not found')
          var jQueryScript = document.createElement('script');
          var pdfScript = document.createElement('script');
          var tableScript = document.createElement('script');
          var actualTable = document.createElement('script');
          jQueryScript.setAttribute('src','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js');
          pdfScript.setAttribute('src','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js');
          tableScript.setAttribute('src','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js');
          actualTable.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.0.28/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js');
          document.head.appendChild(jQueryScript);
          document.head.appendChild(pdfScript);
          document.head.appendChild(tableScript);
          document.head.appendChild(actualTable);
          break;
        }
      }

      return true;


       }
      function fn(a,b,c,e,f) {

        functionCall().then(() => {

//rest of the code
```

Error message

```
 ("jQuery.Deferred exception: doc.autoTable is not a function TypeError: doc.autoTable is not a function")
```

As well as an error message saying .then is undefined.

Comment: Your question should be short and focused.

Comment: It is fairly short, i'm not sure how to make it more focus?

Comment: Do you want remove them or not? In your script you check if a script is already present to not add it again (but it is buggy, as you check only 1 script, but it will add all other scripts again). What you can do is to remove them all or check if they already exists.

Comment: I tried document.head.removeChild() for all 4 scripts i had but i thought that checking if they exist rather than removing them everytime someone performs a button click would be better. So i think checking if they exist is the best way but i could be wrong.

Comment: Are you using php? Because this is easier to implement  with php.

Comment: I can't use any server side technologies since this is being used through a e-commerce cms which does allow for that. So this all has to be on the front end

Comment: Instead of looping through all scripts and then comparing their src, why don’t you simply add a class to the html element - and then check if that class is set, next time the function runs? If so - don’t add scripts again …

Comment: Adding a class when i add the scripts with document.head.appendChild?